# merge few pivot tables in pandas

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas

How I can merge two pandas pivot tables? 
When I try run my code I have error: keyerror

> ```
> data_pivot= pandas.DataFrame(data.pivot_table(values = 'NR_ACTIONS', index=["HOUR", "OPID", "NAME"], columns='CONTACTED_PERSON_NEW', aggfunc='sum'))
> data_pivot.fillna(0, inplace=True)
> data2_pivot= pandas.DataFrame(data2.pivot_table(values = 'AMOUNT_PA', index=["HOUR", "OPID", "NAME"], columns='PA_TYPE', aggfunc='sum'))
> data2_pivot.fillna(0, inplace=True)
> all_data = pandas.merge(data_pivot, data2_pivot, 'left', on = ["HOUR", "OPID", "NAME"] )
> ```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

answer for my question is :

```
data_pivot= pandas.DataFrame(data.pivot_table(values = 'NR_ACTIONS', index=["HOUR", "OPID", "NAME"], columns='CONTACTED_PERSON_NEW', aggfunc='sum'))
data_pivot.fillna(0, inplace=True)
data_pivot.reset_index( inplace=True)
data2_pivot= pandas.DataFrame(data2.pivot_table(values = 'AMOUNT_PA', index=["HOUR", "OPID", "NAME"], columns='PA_TYPE', aggfunc='sum'))
data2_pivot.fillna(0, inplace=True)
data2_pivot.reset_index( inplace=True)
all_data = pandas.merge(data_pivot, data2_pivot, 'left', on = ["HOUR", "OPID", "NAME"] )
```

Comment: that was great, what does the reset_index do that it fixes the key error? thank you

Comment: Had same 'key error' problem after trying to manipulate a df after a pivot_table procedure.  df.reset_index(inplace=true) works!  Although doing a match function ".isin" comparing two df's resulted in a "NoneType" object error, the solution was to leave out the "inplace=true."  So df.reset_index() was the final answer.

Answer (score 0):

The best solution here, if you want to keep the index, would be to tell pandas to merge on the index on the left and right tables. By doing this, you don't need to reset the index.

```
data_pivot= pandas.DataFrame(data.pivot_table(values = 'NR_ACTIONS', index=["HOUR", "OPID", "NAME"], columns='CONTACTED_PERSON_NEW', aggfunc='sum'))
data_pivot.fillna(0, inplace=True)
data2_pivot= pandas.DataFrame(data2.pivot_table(values = 'AMOUNT_PA', index=["HOUR", "OPID", "NAME"], columns='PA_TYPE', aggfunc='sum'))
data2_pivot.fillna(0, inplace=True)

all_data = pandas.merge(data_pivot, data2_pivot, left_index=True,right_index=True )
```

You can always go to [Pandas' doc](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.merge.html) to see the different arguments

PS: If you use multi index, it works, but you need to be careful, the number of keys in the other DataFrame (either the index or a number of columns) must match the number of levels.